# Unable to upload app to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, application-loader

I've been trying to submit my app to iTunes connect, but I've been getting the error `An error occured uploading to the iTunes store`. I've tried this using Xcode and the Application Loader.

I checked the system log and I found these errors:

```
Application Loader[820]:  Error:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 14: **awk: command not found**
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 18: ../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/**iTMSTransporter: No such file or directory**
May 29 11:09:38 Ahmad-MacBook.local Application Loader[820]:  Out:*
```

Here's what I tried to solve this problem:

- some sites suggested that the problem is with Java, so I tried rolling back to Java 1.6 and Java 1.5 and it didn't work, I also installed Java 1.7 from Oracle's website but it didn't work either;
- deleted Xcode and reinstalled it with no success.

Did anyone manage to solve this problem?

I'm running OSX 10.8.3. The current Java version is:

> java version "1.6.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you distributing it to appstore using xcode?. Product>Archive>Distribute>Submit to IOS appstore?

Comment: I've tried Product>Archive>Distribute>Submit to IOS appstore , and I also tried the application loader. I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

i had exactly the same issue and was able to fix it by slightly adapting the file

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter

change the path to the awk to absolute (and i also uncommented the echo of the script path, which probably isn't necessary). Here my changed file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# if the user has the run script in their PATH
# then we can get the path to the script from
# 'which'.  otherwise, we have to get the path
# from $0
if [ "$0" = "iTMSTransporter" ] ; then
  SCRIPT_PATH=`which iTMSTransporter`
else
  SCRIPT_PATH=$0
fi

# get the script's directory
SCRIPT_DIR=`echo $SCRIPT_PATH | /usr/bin/awk -F"/" '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-length($NF))}'`

# call the transporter relative to the script's directory
echo Calling: ${SCRIPT_DIR}../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter "$@"
"${SCRIPT_DIR}../share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter" "$@"
```

i guess this behavior is caused by inproper classpath setup which i wasn't able to resolve though. After fixing the script, i managed to upload my app through the XCode Organiser.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this (type in terminal)

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

Comment: I've already tried this , what should be the result of the command $ java -version after executing these lines ?